# How to delete a single parameter from query string in a URL using JavaScrip/ jQuery(in .net application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have a querystring is as follows.

```
http://tutor.rad.com/abc/login.aspx?eid=123&log=333&add=690000309791436
```

I just want to remove (only string) **"eid=123&"** form URL using JavaScript/jQuery.

Result URL should look like:

```
http://tutor.rad.com/abc/login.aspx?log=333&add=690000309791436
```

I would have used `ULRSearchparams` but IE, Edge (below 17) and Safari (below 10.3) do not support `URLSearchParams` inside URL class.

Please help.

Comment: have you tried `urlStr.split("log")` then start from there

Comment: @Redan I tried but it's gonna split from the first occurrence of 'log' which is 'login' This is what I get..'http://tutor.rad.com/abc/,in.aspx?eid=123&,=333&add=690' Any other ways? Please help.

Comment: i believe you should explore more on `split()` function. it will return an array then you can browse through that to see which strings you need.

Answer (score 0):

First get the url in a string like this:

```
url = window.location.href;
```

then replace the parameter that needs to be removed

```
newURL = url.replace("eid=123&", "");
```

then insert the url again

```
document.location.href = newURL;
```

Comment: 'eid' value is not a constant value, it keeps changing whenever I deal with a different account page. So, replace like that does not work for me. Any other ideas, please?

Comment: Like you can see, vadivel a already answered, but you could put the parameter of "eid" in an input type hidden with php, then when you need to replace the url get the value of the input type hidden and place that in the replace. but this is not an efficient answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace 'yourparamkey' variable value in below code. hope this help you.


function searchToObject() {
  var pairs = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&"),
    obj = {},
    pair,
    i;

  for ( i in pairs ) {
    if ( pairs[i] === "" ) continue;

    pair = pairs[i].split("=");
    obj[ decodeURIComponent( pair[0] ) ] = decodeURIComponent( pair[1] );
  }

  return obj;
}

function serialize(obj) {
  var str = [];
  for(var p in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    }
  return str.join("&");
}

var params = searchToObject();
delete params.yourparamkey; //remove param key
var path = window.location.pathname + '?' + serialize(params);
history.pushState({}, document.title, path);
```